# Notice: Undefined index: img in

Tags: php

Hi I'm learning right now how to upload images to database, but I'm getting this error/notice.

```
 </select>
                <input type="text" name="nama" class="input-control" placeholder="Nama Produk" required>
                <input type="text" name="harga" class="input-control" placeholder="Harga Produk" required>
                <input type="file" name="img" class="input-control" required>
                <textarea class="input-control" name="deskripsi" placeholder="Desrkipsi"></textarea>
                <select class="input-control" name="status">
                    <option value="">--Pilih--</option>
                    <option value="1">Aktif</option>
                    <option value="0">Tidak Aktif</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn-login">
            </form>  
            <?php 
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                    $kategori   = $_POST['kategori'];
                    $nama       = $_POST['nama'];
                    $harga      = $_POST['harga'];
                    $deskripsi  = $_POST['deskripsi'];    
                    $status     = $_POST['status'];

                    $filename = $_FILES['img']['name'];
                    $tmp_name = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    
                }
```

the error output

```
Notice: Undefined index: img in C:\xampp\htdocs\pa_web\tambah_produk.php on line 66
```

Comment: Hi, you should add here, at least, the code of the whole `<form>` tag. Some missing uploads errors come from forgetting to set the form to `multipart/form-data`. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form
https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

> **Note:**
> Be sure your file upload form has attribute
> enctype="multipart/form-data" otherwise the file upload will not work.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to submit file from form you should put "enctype="multipart/form-data".

```
<form "enctype="multipart/form-data" ...> 

</form>
```

Do you put it?